# How do I find a replacement door lock for this?

Tags: doors, lock, deadbolt

I moved into a newly built home and am trying to replace the deadbolt and the lever below. 
But I'm not able to find a replacement lock that replaces my existing locks. All locks I've looked at have rectangular plates that need to be screwed onto the side of the door (see the picture, but I have circular openings on the door with no screws and no rectangular latch plate). I see "Fortis" labeled on one of the deadbolts.

Can anybody help me identify this door lock?

[image: Here's the picture of my door and the door lock]

Comment: 5 minutes with a chisel and/or router to modify the door to suit hardware you can find easily .vs. an agonizing search for oddball hardware. I know what I'd be doing...

Comment: If you're just trying to get new keys for security reasons, have a locksmith re-key them. It's quite cheap if you bring the locks to their shop.

Comment: Is your door a metal clad door? The corner edge of the door along the outside edge seems to indicate that the door may be metal clad. If this is indeed true you will likely want to stay with the round drive in type latch bolts. Trying to mortise in a rectangular latch plate is not a good idea on a metal clad door.

Comment: @Ecnerwal Chiseling won't work as I have an aluminum door at the entrance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks to be like a schlange or kwikset lockset commonly found at Home Depot. You can easily re-cylinder this, but it isn't obvious how to get the lock off.

My solution was as follows:

1. Rotate the lever to the vertical position.  There will be two screws hidden under it.
2. Remove them, and separate the lock into two halves.
3. The lock-half has a cover on it. Remove it.
4. There's a screw that holds the cylinder in.

You can also get a lock/lever combination, as well as new doorknobs -- in many cases you can re-use the existing deadbolt and striker latch and just change the visible hardware.

Answer (score 3):

If you are having a hard time finding the strikes that do not have the rectangular plate, many latchset makers have the round ones like you have in the box with the others. Seems to me that they make the bolts or latch fit into any situation. According to one of the manufacturers the type of bolt you are looking for is called a "drive-in" latch

Or as Ecnerwal suggests, although it may take longer than 5 minutes for a newbie to mortise in the rectangular ones. All it takes is a razor knife, chisel and hammer

Answer (score 2):

Fortis is a schlage product. go onto their web site and you might find what you are looking for. but most schlage products the parts are interchangeable so you can buy new locks and just reuse the latches.

Comment: IIRC, every Schlage lock that I've installed comes with both (annoyingly so).

Answer (score 2):

I know these are older posts but I found it looking for the answer to the same question.  If you search "drive in latch" with the brand name of the lock you are trying to get a round insert lock for instead of the latch plate that you have to carve the door for you will find what you are looking for.  You can buy JUST the dead bolt insert part that matches your lock for cheap.  I paid less than five bucks a piece for mine.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. Thanks for the good answer; hope to see more of your contributions.

Answer (score 1):

you don't have to change the latch, just replace the lock front and back and use new keys. the latch can be left alone.

Comment: This does not provide any  information  that's not already included in the other answers.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to take it off and take it to your local locksmith. You will have a hard time getting it out and should use a Phillips screwdriver to pull it toward you. This type of deadbolt is called a "slam in deadbolt" (at least thats what I call it). You may need to tap the screwdriver with a hammer to get the old one out and the new one in.